# Is there support for minified JS & CSS files to be collocated with a View/Page/Component?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I've been looking into JS/CSS files that are collocated with Views in ASP.NET.Core (.NET 6) MVC. They work well and I can group up my JS, CSS and CSHTML files nicely which is exactly what I want. However, when I minify those files and reference the minified versions they're not able to be found in the root directory which is where collocated files are place on publish.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#load-a-script-from-an-external-javascript-file-js-collocated-with-a-component

The docs above state that files that follow the FILENAME.cshtml.js or FILENAME.cshtml.css format are stripped of their extension (cshtml) and published in the root directory as static files. But I haven't been able to find anywhere that mentions if you can change that format or if it accepts minified files like FILENAME.cshtml.min.js.

I've tried minifying files that are collocated to an element. Like minifying the file FILENAME.cshtml.js to FILENAME.cshtml.min.js and referencing it just how you would according to the documentation. But to no avail, the minified file is not added to the root on publish like the non-minified version is.

I assume this happens because the file name pattern doesn't match the one ASP.NET.Core is looking for when moving them to root, so the files are not moved.

I understand this feature is new in ASP.NET.Core 6, so I've struggled to find anyone with my issue. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How do you minify the file and where did you host the app? Also, you use blazor?

Comment: @Rena Sorry should have mentioned. I’m currently minifying using the BundlerMinifier VS extension, so before build. I’ll be switching to something that handles it on build soon. Hosting app on IIS and no, I’m not using Blazor. Just an ASP.NET.Core 6 MVC app